# matching two columns, excluding empty cells and getting back with the cases

Tags: r, compare, match

i am a beginner here, i am working on comparing email websites to emails. Ex: my email is XXX@yyy.com, my company's website should be www.yyy.com.

i have a list of emails and a list of websites.
i split email and website so now i have a list of

```
website    email
yyy.com     yyy.com
```

it is a long list with empty cells.

i want to compare both columns, skip empty cells and come back with the mismatches rather than TRUE and False.

I have tried `df <- (website==email)`

```
FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [14] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 [27] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [40] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [53] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
 [66] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 [79] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
 [92] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[105]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[118] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[131] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[144] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[157]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[170] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[183] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[196]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[209] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[222] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[235] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[248] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[261] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[274]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[287] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[300] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[313] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[326] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[339] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[352] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[365] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[378]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[391] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[404] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[417] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[430]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[443]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[456] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[469] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[482] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[495] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[508] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[521] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[534] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[547] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[560] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[573]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

I want to know which are false and i am sure some of the false are due to empty cells. 
thank you in advance.

Comment: I have figured this out. I redid the whole process.
created two empty columns in my data frame. used str_replace_all to remove the www. and http parts. used gsub("^([^,]*)@", @"....) to replace first part of email and  keep domain name.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured this out. I redid the whole process. created two empty columns in my data frame. used str_replace_all to remove the www. and http parts. used gsub("^([^,]*)@", @"....) to replace first part of email and keep domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Using the package dplyr (great for filtering or any data manipulation type):

```
library(dplyr)
mismatch <- filter(list, website!=email & !is.na(website) & !is.na(email))
```